# C++ vector out of memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, stdvector

I have a very large vector (millions of entries 1024 bytes each). I am exceeding the maximum size of the vector (getting a bad memory alloc exception). I am doing a recursive operation over the vector of items which requires accessing other elements in the vector. The operations need to be done quickly. I am trying to avoid writing to disk for speed reasons. Is there any other way to store this data that would not require writing to disk? If I have to write the data to disk, what would be the most ideal way to do it>

edit for a few more details.

The operations that I am performing on the data set is generating a string recursively based on other data points in the vector. The data is sorted when it is read in. Data sets ranging from 50,000 to 50,000,0000.

Comment: We can't really say anything without knowing more about your data.

Comment: How much memory is required? How much memory do you have available?

Comment: Do you need to have contiguous memory for whatever it is you're doing? If not, an easy change would be to use an `std::deque` instead; it should allow you to store a lot more elements before running out of memory.

Comment: Most implementations of  `std::vector` use a capacity-doubling reallocation strategy, which means that if you're growing your vector a lot, it probably is using a lot more storage space than is necessary for storing the actual addressable elements.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia It doesn't adaptively back off if it gets an out-of-memory error?

Comment: @Sancho, it's certainly not required to.  I don't know if any implementation actually does that, but I would guess the answer is no for all existing implementations.

Comment: Yes the data needs to be contiguous. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Is your process a 32 bit or 64 bit process?  What OS?

Comment: Your data must be contiguous, but you're considering storing some on disc? Could you give a bit more background info? Because I don't see a situation where data must be contiguous, but storage to disc is being considered as an option.

Comment: @Yakk needs to run on both 32 and 64. Ubuntu 10 and 12.

Comment: 32 bits of memory space, at 1024 bytes per chunk of data, means a theoretical upper bound of `2^22` items (and a practical bound much less than this, because not all of your memory space will be this one container).  This is a mere 4.2 million elements.  You are asking for a contiguous buffer of memory containing "millions" of 1024 byte elements on a 32 bit OS -- the answer is "no, you cannot do that".  Relax some of these, and you can solve it.  Why, exactly, do you need contiguous?

Comment: containers can not contain an infinite number of elements: use `std::vector::max_size()` to determine the max size you can hold.

Comment: @user2174896: Does it _actually_ need to be contiguous, or is random access enough?

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to use [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/). It's a reimplementation of the STL for large structures that transparently writes to disk when the data won't fit in memory.

Comment: If the data has to be contiguous, how will STXXL help?  Any kind of writing to disk (transparent or not) breaks contiguity.

Comment: @Yakk, it's not really contiguous, it just presents the same interface as `std::vector`. The question doesn't ask for it to be contiguous, or at least it didn't when I posted the answer.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple Yeah, the asker added that constraint deep in the comments of the question.

Comment: @Yakk, perhaps "I need infinite contiguous memory" is not a reasonable requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem cannot be solved as stated and clarified in the comments.

You have requested a way to have a contiguous in-memory buffer of 50,000,000 entries of size 1024 on a 32 bit system.

A 32 bit system has only 4294967296 bytes of addressable memory.  You are asking for 51200000000 bytes of addressable memory, or 11.9 times the amount of memory address space on your system.

If you don't require that your data be contiguous and memory-addressable, if you don't require that your data all be in memory at once, or if you relax other requirements, there may be an answer to your problem.  Ie, some OSs expose access to a non-memory space of values that corresponds to RAM (there where ways in 8 gig windows systems to use more than 4 gigs of total RAM) through some hacky interface or other.

But as stated, the answer is "no, you cannot do that".

Comment: Thats what I figured. Thanks.

Comment: @user2174896 to be clear, what my answer means is "you are asking the wrong question", not "you cannot solve your actual problem".  I strongly doubt your actual problem is "51200000000 bytes of continuous memory space on a 32 bit OS"

Answer (score 0):

Because your data must be contiguous, and you know how many elements you need to store, just create a `std::vector` and use the `reserve()` function to attempt to gain a contiguous block of memory of the required size.

There is very little overhead in storing a vector (just a few pointers to manage the beginning and end). This is as good as you'll be able to do.

If that fails:

- add more memory to your machine (may not actually help, if you've run up against addressing or implementation constraints)
- switch to a raw array
- find a way to reduce the size of your elements
- try to find a solution that can tackle the problem in small blocks

Comment: Adding more memory to your machine will do nothing on a modern OS to the max size of a `vector`, assuming the user has allowed for enough virtual memory.  Allocating is about consuming address space, not memory.  Even then, an OS can blythly hand out more address space than they have virtual memory for, and only fail when the memory is actually modified.

Comment: Thats exactly what I figured. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

That is 1GB of memory (1024KB * 10^6 = 1MB * 10^3 = 1GB). Ideally for a 32 bit machine upto 4GB memory operations can be performed.
To answer your question, try first a normal malloc() call and allocate 1 GB of memory. This should be done without any error.
Also, please paste the exact error msg that you get while using the vector.

Comment: Just about the only useful information the OP gives in the question is what error he's seeing - *bad memory alloc exception*, aka [`std::bad_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)

Comment: using **malloc** was an answer :)

Comment: It's a wrong answer. The question says millions, not 1 million. Even assuming it's only 2-3 million, there is no guarantee that a 32-bit machine can allocate 2-3 GB of contiguous address space. Some address space will be used for the kernel, for shared libraries, for the stack, etc.

Comment: The question also says "Millions" of 1024 Bytes.